# How to receive data message when user click on the notification alert and the app was not running

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Under IOS, when the application **is not running**, and I send a message via firebase clound messaging **with notification + data payload**, then on the ios device a notification alert will be shown to the end user. However, when the user click on it, **how to retrieve the data payload of the notification**? Because the app will be launch, but no event will be fired in the application (ie: DidReceiveRemoteNotification is not fired)

Also, when the app is in the background, the notification alert will be also shown to the end user. However, when the user click on it, the event DidReceiveRemoteNotification will be fired with the data payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is closed, the contents of the notification will be delivered in your Appdelegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as `launchOptions` parameter.

What you could do is, to call your `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` method if that happens, for example like this (Objective-C):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// check if a remote notification was received while the app was closed, then take the necessary actions
if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (AppDelegate ) :

```
 // Do what you want to happen when a remote notification is tapped.
            if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
                let userInfo: NSDictionary = launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as! NSDictionary
    }
```